# Alignment is not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I prepared a logo, grouped the entire thing, and then I tried to align it to the artboard. Problem is each time I align the group one of the the text layers shifts its position. I don't want to outline the entire thing, nor do I want to outline that very text.

I don't understand why this is happening. Please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without the file to examine. Could just be a glitch. Can you move the group manually?  Can you perhaps just reposition the text?  Try those.

Comment: I can't explain the *why*.... but it appears as though the text on a path is being effected by the alignment. In other words, the *text alignment* is being changed, as opposed to the *object* alignment.

Comment: @BillyKerr yes I moved that manually. Align didnt work

Comment: @Scott Exactly, I hv nvr faced anythng like that. But I did it manually

Comment: Show us an expanded view of your layer tree.

Comment: @joojaa attached. Kindly check.

Comment: text on a path has been rotated and the align tool is acting on an axis that does not match the visual placement? I think that rotated and transformed items sometimes use two coordinate systems (external object and internal components). Or at least in inDesign this appears to be the case

Comment: @Yorik what if one runs reset transformation?

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the whole logo, expand it to center as a shape and then place your not-traced logo on top (manually), then delete the expanded one.

May not be the best solution but if you feel like your file is not working as intended, that may get you out of trouble for now.

Comment: Thank you so much, Yes I did it manually. Nothing worked. I dnt wanna expand it, Client wanted it as unexpanded. I had to recreat the entire thing but then it worked perfectly. I think its glitch. like a stupid I spend hours trying to fix it, am so angry on myself.